# Differential equation $y' ^2+(y-1)y'-y=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am puzzled over the following differential equation:
$$y' ^2+(y-1)y'-y=0$$
I tried solving for $y$ and got $$y=\frac{y'(y'-1)}{1-y'}$$
But I am not sure where that takes me or if that was even the right approach. Grateful for any tips!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The given equation can be written as $(y'+y)(y'-1)=0$, so either $y'=-y$ or $y'=1$, so $y=Ce^{-x}$ and $y=x+C$ are solutions.

Another solution is a piecewise combination of the above. At any point where we switch between the two forms, we have  $-y = y' = 1$, so $Ce^{-x}=-1$. This can only occur if $C<0$, at $x=\log(-C)=c$, giving the following additional solutions:

$$y(x) = \begin{cases}
-e^{c-x} & x \le c \\
x-c-1 & x \ge c
\end{cases}$$
and 
$$y(x) = \begin{cases}
x-c-1 & x \le c \\
-e^{c-x} & x \ge c
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Thank you. Got it now!

Answer (score 2):

$$y=\frac{y'(y'-1)}{-(y'-1)}=-y'$$ Thus $y=c e^{-x}$ for some $c\in \mathbb R$.

Comment: This misses the $y' = 1$ solution